# prove or disprove: If $c > 0$ and $a < b < c $ , then $a \not \equiv b$ mod $c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

I hope this hasn't been asked already, I tried finding it but couldn't.

I claim it is FALSE:

Let $c > 0$ and $a < b < c$, take $c = 1$ (anything is congruent mod 1) but since $a,b$ are integers, we can let $b = 0$ and $a = -1$ and this works?

Thanks in advance. I am a noob to modular arithmetic. Sorry for being naive.

Comment: As you stated everything is congruent mod $1$ so that case is not interesting. Are you sure it should be $c>0$ and not $a>0$? Because if $a>0$ then the statement would be true. Otherwise it is obviously false.

Comment: I am certain it is $c > 0$ so its just not a very interesting problem then correct since I can let $c$ be 1. its a super intro to number theory course, I am a graduate student but Have never taken any number theory before.

Comment: Well, if you only ask $c>0$ then you can find a counterexample for any $c$, not just $c=1$. For a given $c>0$ just take $b=0$ and $a=-c$.

Comment: True there's many counter examples. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your example works.  Good example of a problem where it is important to know where your variables are drawn from.  For instance, if the problem specified $a,b,c\in \mathbb N$ then it would be true.  In fact, had they not specified $c>0$ I'd have assumed that they meant for the three to be natural numbers.  But the problem should not make us guess.  If you read the problem as $a,b\in \mathbb Z$ and $c\in \mathbb N$ (which I think is the ordinary reading of the claim) then your example is correct.

Comment: Omg yes I initially had thought natural numbers, so just so I know, had we restricted $a,b$ to be natural numbers, this holds true correct?

Comment: Yes it would be correct.  But, just to stress:  as stated the problem doesn't tell us much about $a,b$.  And the fact that the writers go out of their way to tell us that $c>0$ suggests that they were thinking of integers, not natural numbers.  But, really, the burden is on the author to specify this sort of thing.